# The app test users are unable to like the page.

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-like

I'm developing a facebook application and I need test users to test it.

I know that facebook provides now the possibility to create tests users, but they can't "like" a public page and this prevent me to use them because the "likes" is the only thing I need.

Do you know any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Like button code is quite simple, so if the goal of your testing is to make sure it will work properly with Facebook, all you need is to generate Like code using [FB Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) , and you can be confident it works without testing.

If the goal of your testing is testing something else, based on number of responses, and you need a good representation of numbers (e.g. 10, 100, 1000, ...), you have 2 options:

- hook "pseudo like" to some file/db table where you can change it as you want, test with all the numbers you need to test, and then replace with real FB Like
- since Like is based on URL, during testing you could test your logic using Like code for some other pages (that already have different number of likes). For example reference page I gave a link to above, has about 65k likes, so I could use code for that page temporarily to test my logic for 65k likes.

After that you still can test a few numbers by using your friends as test subjects of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, the "pseudo like" can be a quite good solution, even if a an extensive and fast betatest would require to login from facebook in my application, retrieve the likes, change the likes, retrieve again and so on, all this for several users.

Answer (score -1):

If only there were a website where you could ask all of your friends to help you... a website that included the ability for those friends to "like" whatever it is you are working on... you'd have to ensure that those friends were willing to spare a brief moment of the work day to (gasp) *not work* and view the website instead...

Sarcasm aside, I think your best bet will be to ask the people on facebook for a few likes just to help you with a project.

Comment: I need extensive testing, that wouln't be a solution.

Comment: Ah, well apologies friend. I misunderstood. I thought you just needed a couple test Likes to see if everything was functioning properly. I think ksbytes response will best serve you.